# fat free framework find and cast

Tags: php, casting, find, fat-free-framework

I am familiarising myself with the Fat Free Framework. I am trying to query a database and return the result in json format.

```
$user=new DB\SQL\Mapper($db,'wilt');
 $filter = array();
    $option = array(
            'order' => 'created DESC',
            'limit' => 7
    );
    $list=$user->find($filter,$option);
    echo json_encode($list);
```

When I use $list=$user->find($filter,$option);, it returns 3 empty records. When I use $list=$user->cast(), it returns the one record with the fields, but the values are null.

How can I combine find and cast?

Comment: What happens, if you use find() without any parameters? Beside that, you don't need `cast()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this one:

```
$list = array_map(array($user,'cast'),$user->find($filter,$option));
echo json_encode($list);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. This also worked `$list=$user->find($filter,$option);     
    foreach ($list as $obj)
    {
        entries[]=$obj->cast();
    } `. But I'll use yours. Thanks